# How to draw an inductive coupling with circuitikz and TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I'd want to draw a circuit with an inductive coupling, as you can see in the following image:

[image]

What I need now is putting the dots related to the inductive coupling, as well as the power lines. I think I could draw these last ones using TikZ if they were flat, but as they are wavy, I don't know how to do it.

This is the code I've written till now (I've put two lines between both coupled inductors):

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

 \begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (0,0) to [short,o-o] (8,0);
  \draw (0,1.5) to [short,o-] (3,1.5);
  \draw (5,1.5) to [short,-o] (8,1.5);
  \draw (3,1.5) to [inductor] (5,1.5);
  \draw (6,2.5) to [short] (5,2.5) to [inductor] (3,2.5) to [short] (2,2.5) to [short] (2,3.5) to [C] (6,3.5) to [short] (6,2.5);
  \draw (2,3.5) to [short] (2,4.5) to [inductor] (6,4.5) to [short] (6,3.5);
  \draw (2,4.5) to [short] (2,5.5) to [resistor] (6,5.5) to [short] (6,4.5);
  \draw[-] (3.5,1.95) -- (4.5,1.95) node{};
  \draw[-] (3.5,2.05) -- (4.5,2.05) node{};
\end{circuitikz} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

How could I complete this drawing?

Thank you.

Comment: Please make sure that all images are uploaded using the official Stack Exchange interface, i.e. the image icon on top of the text field (shortcut: Ctrl+G). This ensures that all images will always be accessible and won't expire.

Comment: In the future, please always try to post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To draw the "wavy" lines, you can use the `snake` line pattern offered by the `decorations.pathmorphing` library. Play with the `segment length` and `amplitude` parameters to get the exact line style you want.

## Code

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (0,0) to [short,o-o] (8,0);
  \draw (0,1.5) to [short,o-] (3,1.5);
  \draw (5,1.5) to [short,-o] (8,1.5);
  \draw (3,1.5) to [inductor] (5,1.5);
  \draw (6,2.5) to [short] (5,2.5) to [inductor] (3,2.5) to [short] (2,2.5) to [short] (2,3.5) to [C] (6,3.5) to [short] (6,2.5);
  \draw (2,3.5) to [short] (2,4.5) to [inductor] (6,4.5) to [short] (6,3.5);
  \draw (2,4.5) to [short] (2,5.5) to [resistor] (6,5.5) to [short] (6,4.5);
  \draw[-] (3.5,1.95) -- (4.5,1.95) node{};
  \draw[-] (3.5,2.05) -- (4.5,2.05) node{};

  % wavy lines
  \draw[->,decorate,decoration={snake,segment length=30pt,amplitude=4pt}](0,.75)--(2,.75);
  \draw[->,decorate,decoration={snake,segment length=30pt,amplitude=4pt}](6,.75)--(8,.75);
\end{circuitikz} 
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Just realized I missed the arrow style. To change it, replace `->` with `-latex` in the `\draw` command.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use PSTricks:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-circ,pst-plot}
\newcommand*\CurvedArrow[4]{
  \rput(#1,0){
    \psplot[algebraic]{0}{#2}{#3*sin(6*x)+#4}
    \psline{->}(#2,#4)(!#2 0.15 add #4)
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.4,-0.1)(7.3,8.8)
  \wire[arrows=*-*](0,0)(7,0)
  \coil[arrows=*-*](0,2)(7,2){}
  \coil(6,3.5)(1,3.5){}
  \psline(2.5,2.75)(4.5,2.75)
  \capacitor[arrows=*-*](1,5)(6,5){$C$}
  \coil[arrows=*-*](1,6.5)(6,6.5){$L$}
  \resistor[dipolestyle=zigzag](1,8)(6,8){$R$}
  \wire(1,3.5)(1,8)
  \wire(6,3.5)(6,8)
  \psdots[dotsize=2pt](5.5,2.15)(5.5,3.65)
  \rput(6.2,2.15){$n$}
  \rput(6.2,3.65){$l$}
  \CurvedArrow{-0.4}{1.05}{0.2}{1}
  \CurvedArrow{6.1}{1.05}{0.2}{1}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

It can almost certainly be made simpler but here is my first try.

Comment: Those inductors are ugly, but the image it's so much pretty than an output of `circuitikz`, this package maybe is the one thing that I hate of LaTeX.

Comment: @OSjerick If you use the option `dipolestyle=curved` or `dipolestyle=elektor` for the `\coil` macro, the winded wire looks "better".

Answer (score 1):

For the coupling of the inductors, I'd go like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
    (0,0) node[transformer] (T) {}
    (T.A1) node[above] {A1}
    (T.B2) node[anchor=west] {B2}
    (T.A1) node[below right=2mm] {$\bullet$}
    (T.B2) node[above left=2mm] {$\bullet$}
    (T.A1) -| (-1.5,1) to[C] (-3,1) |- (T.A2)
;\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And how do you connect the transformer vertically with the rest of the circuit? It always has those horizontal lines at each node.

Comment: Yeah those lines are part of the node shape: can't get rid of them if using the `transformer` shape.
Otherwise, you just do something like `(T.A1) |- (other node)`

Comment: I don't understand what you say about writing something like `(T.A1) |- (other node)`. Could you give me an example?

Comment: Sure. I edited the answer.